# Проверка на наличия слова в переменной js

Tags: javascript

Есть массив

```
ar quality = ["Старый ", "Новый ", "Долгий "];
```

Есть переменная в которой лежит имя

```
var val = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
```

Как проверить если в этой переменной в начале одно из слов из массива и если есть удалить его?

Например

```
Старый плуг
```

Должна получиться

```
плуг
```

Comment: `val.startsWith()` + цикл по массиву

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом вам поможет метод [str.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).
Псевдокод:

```
var quality = ["Старый ", "Новый ", "Долгий "];
var val = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
for each (word in quality) {
    if val.startsWith(word){
        //удаляем слово
        break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var quality = ["Старый ", "Новый ", "Долгий "], 
    val = 'Старый плуг';   // document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
    
let word = val.substr(0, val.indexOf(' ') + 1);
if (quality.indexOf(word) !== -1)
  val = val.slice(word.length); 
console.log(val);
```

Слова в массиве можно хранить без пробела в конце (тогда `+ 1` у второго параметра `substr` надо будет перенести к параметру `slice`).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const quality = ["Старый ", "Новый ", "Долгий "];

let val = document.getElementById("name").innerText;

quality.some(q => {
  if (val.startsWith(q)) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerText = val.replace(q, '');
    return true;
  }
  return false;
})
```

```html
<div id="name">Новый плуг</div>
```